# Scrapy: Spidering beyond the initial site

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to build a pretty simple crawler to start at a site, and crawl not just that site, but external links as well (branching out *n* sites from the starting site eventually). Currently, it does hit the external links and pulls the first linked page, but I can't make it go beyond that.

Here's my current spider:

```
import scrapy
import json
from seocrawler.items import SeocrawlerItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider

class SeocrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "seocrawler_spider"
    start_urls =  ['http://www.example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)

        next_url = response.css(
            "a::attr('href')"
            ).extract_first()
            if next_url:
                yield scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.parse) 

    def parse_page(self, response):
        item = SeocrawlerItem()
        item['page_link'] = response.url
        item['page_title'] = response.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
        item['page_meta_description'] = response.xpath('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
        item['page_h1'] = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

I've tried setting `DEPTH_LIMIT` to 0 and to a high number, but it doesn't seem to affect it. `request_depth_max` gets reported as 1 no matter what.

What am I missing here?

Comment: use `scrapy.Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider`

Comment: I actually tried that already (probably should've mentioned that); didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: can you check the log and confirm that dupefilters is not filtering out request, also try with dont_filter=True and see if that works

Comment: @MrPandav, I've tried `dont_filter=True`, as well as adding `DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy.dupefilter.BaseDupeFilter'`. It crawls the `start_url`'s site, as well as the first links of external domains off that start domain, but no deeper. Adding those two settings just makes it crawl everything over and over, but it never advances beyond the first link of external links.

Comment: did you check the log ,  ``next_url = response.css(
            "a::attr('href')"
            ).extract_first()`` this code must be visiting same first url everytime you request...like home page or something , you need some logic to make sure it is not visiting same page always